# What kind of grammar is it? "You may see me struggle, but you will never see me quit"

Tags: grammar

Could you tell me what kind of grammar is it?

I mean how can the object `me` can be concatenated with the verb `struggle`? This kind of grammar looks new to me.

[image]

Is there any difference with the following?

> You may see my struggle but you will never see my quit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *You may see me struggle but you will never see me quit.*

"See" is a catenative verb and this is a catenative construction. "Me" is direct object of "see", and the understood subject of the infinitival clause "struggle".

If you replace "me" with "my", the grammar and meaning change, since "struggle" switches from a verb to a noun functioning as direct object  of "see".

Same applies to the "quit" clause

Comment: @GoldDiggingProgrammer Direct object. I've edited my answer for clarity.

Comment: The first link he/she gave is helpful to me. :-)

Comment: @GoldDiggingProgrammer The first link is OK, since "struggle" is a bare infinitival clause. The second link is nonsense -- there is no such thing as a 'complex object'.

Answer (score 0):

It's called "***a bare Infinitive***".

According to [English Grammar](https://www.englishgrammar.org/bare-infinitive-2/):
"When an infinitive is used without the marker *to* it is called a bare infinitive.

The infinitive is used without to after certain verbs like *bid, let, make, see, hear, need, dare* etc."

This bare infinitive is a part of "the Objective-with-the-Infinitive construction".

According to [English Grammar:](https://gramaren.ru/grammar/nff/inf/the-objective-with-the-infinitive-construction)
"The Objective-with-the-Infinitive construction is a construction in which the Infinitive is in predicate relation to a noun in the Common Case or to a pronoun in the Objective case:

I saw him cross the street."

Comment: No it's not. "Him struggle" is not a complex object (not a constituent). That's a ridiculous analysis. In the OP's example, "me" is the direct object of "see" and the _understood_ subject of the subordinate clause "struggle".